# How to ivy:install multiple modules and their sources and javadocs (i.e. everything that is ivy cache)?

Tags: ivy

So I'm creating my own ivy repository. I have went through [the tutorial for building the repository](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/build-repository.html) and the basic task of installing one module works flawlessly. Of course, there we have examples of installing one module. Actually the [ant task install](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/install.html) can do only one module at the time. Since I'd like to store everything that's in the cache in the repository, it would be quite tedious to do that by running one module at the time...

Other then writing some kind of a `build.xml` generator that would have `install` task for each of the module I need/have, is there an easier way to do this? If there is some trick to use some kind of meta ivy.xml that has all the dependencies I need installed, that would also be ok.

In addition if I run install on one module with `transitive=true`, for example module *M*, in my repo I have *M's* jar,sources,javadoc and everything, but for *M's* dependencies - only the jars. How would I install sources,javadocs,etc of transitively dependent modules?

Comment: Have you considered using a Maven repository manager like Sonatype Nexus or JFrog Artifactory to cache the content of remote repositories like Maven Central. I understand you might prefer your own repo format, but in my opinion the Maven repo format is close to an industry standard. Ivy is a flexible client that understands the Maven format in any case.

Comment: I haven't no, mostly because I used maven a long time a go for a little while, switched to an+tivy and never looked back :) But good idea, ivy does read a maven repo easily so I could create another maven repo and simply use it. Thanks Mark!